# Create Dummy Variable (in diff values) with Loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to generate a loop to test a dummy for different values.

This is my dummy

```
df['dummy_medianrat'] = df['median_rating'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 13 else 0)
```

I want to test variables at different value, for example:

test dummy with values < 12 (assume value 1)
test dummy with values < 11

etc

My dummy contains 22 value which describe 22 different rating value (to examine).

How can I test in loop?

Dataframe imported as pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to have something like this:

```
for comp_val in [13, 12, 11]:
    df['dummy_medianrat_for_val_' + str(comp_val)] = df['median_rating']
        .apply(lambda x: 1 if x < comp_val else 0)
```

EDIT: If case you wish to split datasets you can change your code a bit:

```
for comp_val in [13, 12, 11]:
    df_key = 'dummy_medianrat_for_val_' + str(comp_val)
    df[df_key] = df['median_rating'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < comp_val else 0)
    df_lowr = df[df[df_key] == 1]
    df_higr = df[df[df_key] == 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, worked! 

But now, how when I split variables in low e high (0 and 1)?

`#Splitting data in two datasets

df_lowr = df[df['dummy_medianrat'] == 1]
df_higr = df[df['dummy_medianrat'] == 0]`

Can I use always loop? Because I want to test each one every time. If yes, how can I do that? Thank you

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but I have one another problem:
after split I want to assign X e Y to one of dummy generated casually from loop and test each one.
Before loop I used this code:

```X = df_downsample.drop('dummy_medianrat', axis=1).copy()
X.head()```

Same for ```Y =```

how can I solve them? I'm working on Support Vector Machine, so it will classify in 0 and 1 my casual dummy from loop

Comment: Moreover I want that loop it's working generating each kernel run a casual dummy (13, 12 or 11 for example), generating ever different figure after that.
For example: first run of code, it run me only dummy 13, second run only dummy 12, third run only dummy 13 and so on..

Comment: I modified the code as:

```for comp_val in [15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7]:
    df_key = 'dummy_medianrat_for_val_' + str(comp_val)
    df['df_key'] = df['median_rating'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < comp_val else 0)
    df_lowr = df[df['df_key'] == 1]
    df_higr = df[df['df_key'] == 0]
    df_downsample = pd.concat([df_lowr, df_higr])
    len(df_downsample)
    X = df_downsample.drop('df_key', axis=1).copy()
    X.head()
    y = df_downsample['df_key'].copy()
    y.head()```